# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code that I saved as re.py

```
import sys
pattern  ="Fred"
import re
regexp = re.compile(pattern)

for line in sys.stdin:
    result = regexp.search(line)
    if result:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

When I execute this file in terminal -

```
$python re.py < names.txt
```

**Error** appears

```
regexp = re.compile(pattern)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

When I change the file name to test.py

```
$python test.py < names.txt
```

still produces the same error

```
regexp = re.compile(pattern)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

What is causing the error and how to fix it? Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename your script from `re.py` to something else. The name you have chosen is *shadowing* the `re` module you intend to use.

Comment: Thank you, but $python test.py < names.txt sill produces the same error

Comment: Do you still that have `re.py` somewhere in that directory?

Comment: It requires the removal of re.py and re.pyc both. Thanks! Now the problem is solved.